# How to get socket emitted data in express' different route?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, socket.io

I have three files called index.html, result.html and app.js. I can emit data on button click and get printed on the server but I can't get the value on result.html. What I'm missing here?

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to do this kind of thing: [recordit.co/peXqfcU7pi](http://recordit.co/peXqfcU7pi). As @jfriend00 clarified the process the original question chaged. I'm now asking what will I need to for real-time voting system as it is in the recorded screen?

**UPDATE-2** I want to make real-time voting system. When the user vote for something, result page will be updated simultaneously. From @jfriend00's description I got the idea, and I think I need to use SPA for this. However, I'm looking for the best practice.

index.html

```
var socket = io();
    new Vue({
      el: "#points",
      data: {
        points: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
      },
      methods: {
        sendPoint(point) {
          socket.emit('clientEvent', point)
        }
      }
    });
```

in app.js

```
    app.get('/result', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/result.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('clientEvent', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('clientEvent', data)
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});
```

result.html

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('clientEvent', function (data){
      console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this logically.

1. Your browser loads `index.html`.
2. You click the button.
3. Code in `index.html` does `socket.emit('clientEvent', point)` to send data to server.
4. Server receives `clientEvent` and `point` data.
5. Server sends `clientEvent` and `point` data back to the same socket.io connection.
6. Message goes back to the socket.io connection in `index.html`.

No message of this type is ever sent to the `result.html` page.  When that page loads into the browser, it will be an entirely new socket.io connection and no data is sent to that connection from your server.

Since the page that is loaded at the time you send the data to the server is `index.html` it is unclear what exactly you are expecting to happen or what problem you are trying to solve when `result.html` is loaded some time later.  With more description of the actual desired outcome, we could perhaps help more specifically, but the above description explains why no data is sent to `result.html`.

---

Info for your revised question.

Here's the basic process:

1. Handle incoming vote messages or ajax calls (your choice how you send a vote in).
2. Add to the server-based total.
3. Broadcast a `newTotal` message update to all connected clients over socket.io with `io.emit('newTotal', data)`.
4. In the result.html page (or any page that wishes to display the current vote totals), listen for the `newTotal` message and when you receive it, update the displayed total in the page's HTML.
5. When the `results.html` page is requested, fill in the current total before sending the HTML (a template engine would make this easy).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Here it is an example for what I'm looking for. http://recordit.co/peXqfcU7pi 
I need to implement that for my small project.

Comment: @esilik - You'll have to describe the functionality you are looking for in words and add it to your question.  I don't follow what you want from one video snippet.